# SendSignedTransaction is not sending tokens

Tags: web3js, tokens, erc-20, ethereumjs

I tried to use sendSignedTransaction function, it signed and sent the transaction successfully(i think), but it's not transferring tokens as it ought to. It's basically not doing the intended task

Please, i need some help. Below is a link to the gist on GitHub

https://gist.github.com/SirPhemmiey/f2d0b6c1cbf5588abe38bf6b2beddc92

Comment: Do you have the hash from a failed transaction we can inspect?

Comment: Yes, i do. But unfortunately, it's on my private blockchain (Ganache)

Comment: In order to use `transferFrom` from a contract the token's owner must have called previously `approve` on the contract address. Your contract checks for `allowance` and revert, so that might be a possible place where to look for.